How to restore settings obtained by gsettings list-recursive
I did a dconf reset after doing gsettings list-recursive.  How do I use the output from list-recursive to restore settings to the way they were before the reset?  I am running Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit.

Please add an Ubuntu version number to your question.
